# FTP Server Installing on Pi 3 Debian Strench 9

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, file-sharing, file-server, share

I want make a FTP server. I don't want apache or PHP, just FTP. I tried **VSFTPD**, **ProFTPD**, **PureFTPD** and **Samba** but they were not work. Lastest I tried the ProFTPD but when i restart the ProFTPD service it says:

```
Uknown configuration directive at line 8: Include ....
```

(or like that)

PureFTPD was worked but I could not configure. (Virtual Users, Directories, and Anonymous users etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand why **VSFTPD, ProFTPD, PureFTPD** should not work. They all are available from the default Raspbian repository. You should be able to just install one of them, configure and run it.

But anyway, if you use default Raspbian Stretch then there is no need to install any FTP server. `ssh` has a sftp server module that is installed by default:

```
rpi ~$ apt list openssh-sftp-server
Listing... Done
openssh-sftp-server/stable,now 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
```

So if you have `ssh` enabled you can just use its ftp server module out of the box, for example from any other linux machine:

```
linux ~$ sftp pi@192.168.50.237
pi@192.168.50.237's password:
Connected to 192.168.50.237.
sftp>
```

Because **sftp** is based on **ssh** you can just create default unix accounts for users, for example:

`rpi ~$ sudo adduser myuser`

`linux ~$ sftp myuser@192.168.50.237`

**sftp** contains the word *secure* so it is not meant to have an anonymous access. But you can create an account **anonymous** without password authentication so you have an anonymous login. You should be aware of its security risks and how to avoid them. To make an anonymous account for **sftp** you can look at [Anonymous SFTP on Ubuntu](https://singpolyma.net/2009/11/anonymous-sftp-on-ubuntu/).

To block access to user `pi` just give him a password that nobody knows.

You can look here to [Allow SFTP but disallow SSH](https://serverfault.com/q/354615/458473).

Comment: So, how can i create users (Like Virtual users) and configure them, or set Anonymous user?

Comment: @devman2002 I have updated my answer.

Comment: So, can i block access to user 'pi'? and can I disable SSH connect?

Comment: @devman2002 I have updated my answer.